# Error raised by redirected DIR command: "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I ran the following command on `C:` drive of my laptop (Windows 7 Home), and the result contains `The parameter is incorrect`:

```
DIR /S /ON C:\ > "M:\Backup\170114\C_Drive_content.txt"
```

> ```
> The parameter is incorrect.
> ```

I used the same command to other drives of my laptop, no such error occurs. I doubt if there are some long path system hidden files or paths on `C:` drive caused the error.

Could you please give me any hint for this problem?

Comment: Maybe it should be `If not Exist "M:\Backup\170114" md "M:\Backup\170114"` followed by  `DIR /S /ON C:\ >"M:\Backup\170114\C_Drive_content.txt"`

Comment: I don't see how that command can give the error message that you cite - all parameters are correct (or at least valid syntax). Are you intending to list files from two different locations?, as that is what that command will do.  Please post the ***exact*** command and error message. I suspect that neither is true in your question.

Comment: Are you using cmd or powershell?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the command is: DIR /S /ON C:\ > "M:\Backup\170114\C_Drive_content.txt". The command for sure can list all files and folder names to the output file, however, inside the output, there are 4 or 5 lines says: "The parameter is incorrect." Thank you very much.

Comment: it is just DOS cmd, not powershell. Thank you.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: What drive type is `M:`?

Comment: M drive is a USB drive. Thanks. I wanted to list all filenames and folder names on C/D/E drivers (which are internal hard drive, C is the windows system drive) to M drive. I only the similar commands; work on D & E drive, but only the output of C drive contains the error message.

Comment: M drive is a USB drive. I wanted to list all filenames and folder names of C/D/E drives (which are logic drives from one internal hard drive) to the M drive. Drive C is the windows system drive. I ran similar DIR commands, which work on both D & E drive, but only the output of C drive contains the error message: "The parameter is incorrect". DIR did completed traversing all folders on C drive and end successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this error message, but only by reading from a floppy created by an Atari ST with bad date / time stamps on the files. After setting a proper date and time on the Atari ST, and then copying files to a freshly formatted floppy the error message went away.

On a side note, if I ran MSDOS from either a virtual machine or from a boot floppy, I did not get this error when doing a DIR on the floppy with the bad date and time stamps. I only get the error message when running Windows XP. (I don't have a floppy drive on my system with Windows 7 / 10).

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when performing dir d: on a drive with hidden folders such as .usb. The command dir d: /AH showed the hidden files without the error. The command dir d: > fls.txt displayed the error on screen but created fls.txt with a list of non-hidden files.